# Formulário não importa "values" do banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql, formulário, crud

No meu sistema tem uma página de cadastro e uma página com uma tabela com as informações dos cadastrados. Nessa tabela tem um botão de edição que linka com um formulário igual da página de cadastro.

**O que deveria acontecer:**

Os campos dessa página de edição deveriam estar preenchidos com as informações da linha da tabela (registro) que estava o botão de editar.

Ao clicar no botão salvar, os campos modificados deveriam ser alterados no registro.

**O que está acontecendo:**

Embora pareça tudo normal com a função do PHP responsável por importar as informações desse registro pro `value` do campo, não está importando.

Além disso, quando tento alterar o registro aparece o alert indicando que foi alterado com sucesso, mas quando abro no phpMyAdmin, o registro não foi alterado.

**A conexão:**

```
<?php
    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db_formacao");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
       echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
?>
```

**A tabela:**

```
<?php
//Conexão e consulta ao Mysql
mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('db_formacao') or die(mysql_error());
$qry = mysql_query("select * from participantes");

//Pegando os nomes dos campos
$num_fields = mysql_num_fields($qry);//Obtém o número de campos do resultado

for($i = 0;$i<$num_fields; $i++){//Pega o nome dos campos
    $fields[] = mysql_field_name($qry,$i);
}

//Montando o cabeçalho da tabela
$table = '<table class="table table-hover table-inverse" style="margin-top:50;background-color: #37444a; color:lightgrey;"> <tr>';

for($i = 0;$i < $num_fields; $i++){
    $table .= '<th>'.$fields[$i].'</th>';
}

//Montando o corpo da tabela
$table .= '<tbody style="
    background-color: #86979e;
    color: #37444a;    
">';
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($qry)){
    $table .= '<tr>';
    for($i = 0;$i < $num_fields; $i++){
        $table .= '<td>'.$r[$fields[$i]].'</td>';
    }

    // Adicionando botão de exclusão
    $table .= '<td><form action="FormEdicao.php" method="post">'; //formulário com método post que vai para deleteF.php
    $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="ID" value="'.$r['ID'].'">';
    $table .= '<button class="btn btn-primary">Editar</button>'; //aqui está o seu botão
    $table .= '</form></td>';
}

//Finalizando a tabela
$table .= '</tbody></table>';

//Imprimindo a tabela
echo $table;

?>
```

**Formulário de edição:**

```
  <?php
    require 'conn.php';
    $queryColaboradores = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT FORMACAO FROM participantes");
    $turma = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'TURMA');
    $formacao = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'FORMACAO');
    $colaborador = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'COLABORADOR');
    $Realizado = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'REALIZADO');
    $id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'ID');
    var_dump($turma, $formacao, $colaborador);
    /* NULL NULL NULL */
?>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h1 style="
                    margin-top:100px;">Inscrição</h1>
                <p> </p>
                <p class="lead"></p>
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <form id="cadastro" method="post" action="banco/updateEdicao.php" style="
                        text-align: left;
                        margin-top:50px;">
                        <fieldset disabled>
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <div class="form-group" method="post" style="
                                text-align: left;">
                                    <label  for="TURMA">ID participante: </label>
                                    <input  type="text" required class="form-control" id="PARTICIPANTE" name="PARTICIPANTE" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="'.['ID'].'"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset disabled>
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <div class="form-group" style="
                            text-align: left;">
                                    <label  for="FORMACAO">Formação: </label>
                                    <input  type="text" required class="form-control" id="FORMACAO" name="FORMACAO" value="<?php echo $formacao; ?>">
                                 </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset disabled>
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <div class="form-group" method="post" style="
                            text-align: left;">
                                    <label  for="TURMA">Turma: </label>
                                    <input  type="text" required class="form-control" id="TURMA" name="TURMA" value="<?php echo $turma; ?>">
                                 </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset disabled>
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <div class="form-group" method="post" style="
                            text-align: left;">
                                    <label  for="TURMA">Colaborador: </label>
                                    <input  type="text" required class="form-control" id="COLABORADOR" name="COLABORADOR" value="<?php echo $colaborador; ?>">
                                 </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <fieldset disabled>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="previsto">Status</label>
                                    <input type="text" id="PREVISTO" name="PREVISTO" class="form-control" value="Previsto">
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div class="form-group" style="
                                text-align: left;">
                                <label  for="REALIZADO">Realizado: </label>
                                <input  type="text" required class="form-control" id="REALIZADO" name="REALIZADO" value="Realizado">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Salvar</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**O update:**

```
<?php

$previsto = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'PREVISTO');
$realizado = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'REALIZADO');
$id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'ID');

$strcon = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'db_formacao') or die('Erro ao conectar ao banco de dados');
$sql = " UPDATE participantes SET REALIZADO = '$realizado' WHERE ID = '$id'";
mysqli_query($strcon,$sql) or die("Erro ao tentar atualizar registro. " . mysqli_error($strcon));
mysqli_close($strcon);

echo '<script type="text/javascript">
            alert("Salvo com Sucesso !");

        </script>';

var_dump($previsto, $realizado, $id); 
/*Ta pegando as informações certas digitadas no campo Realizado, mas não ta armazenando*/
?>
```

**Atualização:** Quando vou salvar o update, aparece o script que diz que o registro foi alterado com sucesso, mas quando abro a tabela no phpMyAdmin, o registro não foi alterado.
Além disso, o formulário continua não importando os "values" do banco;

**Dei um var_dump($previsto, $realizado, $id); e aparece NULL NULL NULL**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: No banco de dados atualiza normal? Ou também não atualiza, igual no values?

Comment: Então, quando eu tento alterar aparece o recado "Erro ao tentar alterar registro", mas a conexão ta certinha.

Comment: No arquivo update, tenta exibir o erro que está acontecendo no sql. Aqui: `try {
    mysqli_query($strcon, $sql);
} catch (Exception $e) {echo mysqli_error($strcon);
    die("Erro ao tentar alterar registro");
}`

Comment: Então, não dá pra ver o erro porque logo aparece o script de "salvo com sucesso" e redireciona pra pagina anterior

Comment: Eu tirei o window.history.go pra ver se o erro aparecia na página update, mas não, ta em branco, limpinha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A resposta era mais simples do que eu pensava.

Na página da **Tabela** temos:

```
$table .= '<input type="hidden" name="ID" value="'.$r['ID'].'">';
```

Isso garante que o ID está sendo passado quando o botão de edição for clicado.

Fazendo o mesmo para os outros campos também:

```
    $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="ID" value="'.$r['ID'].'">';
    $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="FORMACAO" value="'.$r['FORMACAO'].'">';
    $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="TURMA" value="'.$r['TURMA'].'">';
    $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="COLABORADOR" value="'.$r['COLABORADOR'].'">';
```

Problema Resolvido! :)