# Update não atualiza registros do banco

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, crud

No meu sistema tem uma página de cadastro e uma página com uma tabela com as informações dos cadastrados. Nessa tabela tem um botão de edição que linka com um formulário igual da página de cadastro.

**O que deveria acontecer:**

Ao clicar no botão salvar, os campos modificados deveriam ser alterados no registro.

**O que está acontecendo:**

Quando tento alterar o registro aparece o `alert` de "salvo com sucesso" e volta pra página anterior, como deveria acontecer. Mas olhando pelo phpMyAdmin, o registro continua inalterado

**A conexão:**

```
<?php
    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db_formacao");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
       echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
?>
```

**Formulário de edição:**

```
<?php
    require 'conn.php';
    $queryColaboradores = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT FORMACAO FROM participantes");
    $turma = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'TURMA');
    $formacao = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'FORMACAO');
    $colaborador = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'COLABORADOR');
    $Realizado = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'REALIZADO');
    $id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'ID');
    var_dump($queryColaboradores);
?>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h1 style="
                    margin-top:100px;">Inscrição</h1>
                <p> </p>
                <p class="lead"></p>
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <form id="cadastro" method="post" action="banco/updateEdicao.php" style="
                        text-align: left;
                        margin-top:50px;">
                        <fieldset disabled>
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <div class="form-group" style="
                            text-align: left;">
                                    <label  for="FORMACAO">Formação: </label>
                                    <input  type="text" required class="form-control" id="FORMACAO" name="FORMACAO" value="<?php echo $formacao; ?>">
                                 </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset disabled>
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <div class="form-group" method="post" style="
                            text-align: left;">
                                    <label  for="TURMA">Turma: </label>
                                    <input  type="text" required class="form-control" id="TURMA" name="TURMA" value="<?php echo $turma; ?>">
                                 </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset disabled>
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <div class="form-group" method="post" style="
                            text-align: left;">
                                    <label  for="TURMA">Colaborador: </label>
                                    <input  type="text" required class="form-control" id="COLABORADOR" name="COLABORADOR" value="<?php echo $colaborador; ?>">
                                 </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset disabled>
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <div class="form-group" method="post" style="
                                text-align: left;">
                                    <label  for="TURMA">ID participante: </label>
                                    <input  type="text" required class="form-control" id="PARTICIPANTE" name="PARTICIPANTE" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id ?>" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <fieldset disabled>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="previsto">Status</label>
                                    <input type="text" id="PREVISTO" name="PREVISTO" class="form-control" value="Previsto">
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div class="form-group" style="
                                text-align: left;">
                                <label  for="REALIZADO">Realizado: </label>
                                <input  type="text" required class="form-control" id="REALIZADO" name="REALIZADO" value="Realizado">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Salvar</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**O update:**

```
<?php

$previsto = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'PREVISTO');
$realizado = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'REALIZADO');
$id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'ID');

$strcon = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'db_formacao') or die('Erro ao conectar ao banco de dados');
$sql = " UPDATE participantes SET REALIZADO = '$realizado' WHERE ID = '$id' ";
mysqli_query($strcon,$sql) or die("Erro ao tentar atualizar registro. " . mysqli_error($strcon));
mysqli_close($strcon);

echo '<script type="text/javascript">
            alert("Salvo com Sucesso !");
            window.history.go(-1);
        </script>';

var_dump($id)
?>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**OBS:** Se eu tirar o `WHERE ID = '$id'` todos os registros são atualizados normalmente, mas com o WHERE não.

Comment: Você já viu se você está mesmo recebendo o valor do ID em `$id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'ID');` ? As vezes a variavel `$id` está vindo nulla.

Comment: Sim, eu dei um var_dump e está recebendo NULL

Comment: Pelo seu código, toda vez que você chamar essa página de update ele vai aparecer `Alterado com sucesso`, sugiro que faça uma verificação para ver se realmente está sendo alterado no banco utilizando `mysqli_affected_rows($con);`, sugiro também que retire o `window.history.go(-1);` para permanecer na página e você conseguir ver o erro.

Comment: Estou verificando se o registro está sendo alterado pelo phpMyAdmin, já tirei o window.history.go(-1) pra ver o erro mas só printa o var_dump.

Comment: Disabled não passa o valor para o fomulário, além de não poder editar.  <fieldset disabled>

Comment: Sim, não poder editar é exatamente o que eu quero para os campos que estão com o disabled, que são os campos que foram preenchidos na hora do cadastro. Só um campo está disponível para edição, que é o Realizado.

Comment: Eu tenho um capo disabled que está recebendo o valor do ID da participação a ser editada.

Comment: Readonly envia o valor para o formulário e também não pode editar

Comment: Vou colocar uma imagem do meu formulário.

Comment: Vou colocar o link de uma outra pergunta minha sobre outro problema no mesmo formulário que tem a ver com o que você está dizendo. Os campos disabled deviam estar recebendo um value importado do banco e não está recebendo.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/234124/formul%C3%A1rio-n%C3%A3o-importa-values-do-banco-de-dados

Comment: seu formulario está um tanto curioso, disabled com required mas não pode editar

Comment: Porque eu quero que esse campo exista e seja preenchido com as informações vindas da tabela do banco, mas que não possa editar. Isso só pra mostrar ao usuário as informações que ele digitou no cadastro anterior, mas que ele não pode alterar. O único campo alterável é o último, o Realizado.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65177/discussion-between-mariana-ferreira-and-leo-caracciolo).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id ?>" />` por estar dentro de `<fieldset disabled>` além de não poder editar não passa o valor.

Já que o input do id é do tipo hidden você pode colocar ele no final do formulário, fora do `<fieldset disabled>` alterando o `name="id"` para `name="ID"` pois parece ser também problema **Case-sensitive**

```
 ................
 ................
 <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="<?php echo $id ?>" />
 </form>
```

> **ou se preferir não mudar o name do input**

na edicao `$id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'id');`

na update `$id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'id');`

pois este `id` no `filter_input` parece ser **Case-sensitive**